# Running a function based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to enter the word login into the console and have my function run. (I am fairly new to Python so if I don't understand some of the scripts you are sending bear with me.)

I expect the output to be Login successful.

The function I want to run is the following (or Log_in):

```
def log_in():
    print("Username:"); print('Batman_20082')
    print("Password:"); print('*******')
    print("Logging in! Please Wait")

log_in();
```

## Second Question

Hello! 
I am working on a python login logout feature! I want to cancel the logout feature if the login feature hasn't been used.

```
def log_in():
  print("Username:"); print('Batman_20082')
  print("Password:"); print('*******')
  print("Logging in! Please Wait")

if(input() == 'login'):
    log_in()

def log_out():
  print("Successfully logged out!")

if(input() == 'logout'):
  log_out()
```

Code Above!
Thanks to GLHR for the help with the if input code!
I would highly appreciate if you help me get to 15 rep! So i can plus rep the people that help me!

I want to be the output to be, you haven't logged in yet. or something like that.

Comment: Look at how to take input from user in python via input function if this is python3 you are working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `input()` method to get user input and compare it to the command `login`. If they match, run your function:

```
def log_in():
  print("Username:"); print('Batman_20082')
  print("Password:"); print('*******')
  print("Logging in! Please Wait")

if input() == 'login':
    log_in()
```

`input()` will wait till the user presses Enter.

If you want to keep asking for the command until a valid command is answered (instead of quitting after the first command), you can use a `while` loop instead:

```
while input() != 'login':
    print("Invalid command, try again")

log_in()
```